# How to get the day of the week from the day number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, date

Given `dayNumber` is from `0` - `6` representing `Monday` - `Sunday` respectively.

Can the `Date` / `String` objects be used to get the day of the week from `dayNumber`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the day from a particular date using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495644/how-to-get-the-day-from-a-particular-date-using-javascript)

Comment: [MDN Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to get the day of week and the month of the year?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822852/javascript-how-to-get-the-day-of-week-and-the-month-of-the-year)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This will give you a day based on the index you pass:

```
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Monday";
weekday[1]="Tuesday";
weekday[2]="Wednesday";
weekday[3]="Thursday";
weekday[4]="Friday";
weekday[5]="Saturday";
weekday[6]="Sunday";
console.log("Today is " + weekday[3]);
```

Outputs "Today is Thursday"

You can alse get the current days index from JavaScript with `getDay()` (however in this method, Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, etc.):

```
var d=new Date();
console.log(d.getDay());
```

Outputs 1 when it's Monday.

Comment: `var dayOfWeek = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];`

Comment: Well, its most obvious way, though if it could be done without using extra arrays and using only the Date api of js would be great, still thanks for the answer

Answer (score 108):

A much more elegant way which allows you to also show the weekday by locale if you choose to is available starting the latest version of ECMA scripts and is running in all latest browsers and node.js:

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString('en-us', {  weekday: 'long' }));
```

Comment: Just a warning to anyone using this, it works well, but this is a very heavy way to get this. Only use it when you have few dates that you need to convert and not on a sever side nodejs application. If you run this on 10k dates, it takes a long time and there's a memory leak.

Comment: @omer, did you happen to open an issue with the node team? I think we can all benefit from this working faster and with no memory leaks.

Comment: No I didn't yet but I will open it now, good idea. I managed to reproduce it with a simple while loop that runs 10k times. I am not sure if it's actually a bug or just that this function is heavy on resources for this specific use case.

Comment: For performance, MDN authors recommend: "When formatting large numbers of dates, it is better to create an Intl.DateTimeFormat object and use the function provided by its format property." Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: Might want to use `navigator.language` instead of `'en-us'`. So the user gets her Mondays in the language of her choosing.

Comment: @sean The performance impact has either been addressed or is now negligible. The aforementioned tip for formatting by MDN has since been removed, although it exists in other versions like [german](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#performance). For Chromium-based browsers and therefore V8, I think it's a ghost from the past, see: https://v8.dev/blog/intl

Answer (score 36):

This code is a modified version of what is given above. It returns the string representing the day instead

```
/**
* Converts a day number to a string.
*
* @param {Number} dayIndex
* @return {String} Returns day as string
*/
function dayOfWeekAsString(dayIndex) {
  return ["Sunday", "Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][dayIndex] || '';
}
```

**For example**

```
dayOfWeekAsString(0) returns "Sunday"
```

Comment: This is incorrect since `getDay()` implementations starts on `Sunday`.

It should be instead:

return ["Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][dayIndex];

Answer (score 9):

```
/**
* I convert a day string to an number.
*
* @method dayOfWeekAsInteger
* @param {String} day
* @return {Number} Returns day as number
*/
function dayOfWeekAsInteger(day) {
  return ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"].indexOf(day);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This will add a getDayOfWeek() function as a prototype to the JavaScript Date class.

```
Date.prototype.getDayOfWeek = function(){   
    return ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][ this.getDay() ];
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The first solution is very straightforward since we just use [getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) to get the day of week, from `0` (Sunday) to `6` (Saturday).

```js
var dayOfTheWeek = (day, month, year) => {
  const weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  return weekday[new Date(`${month}/${day}/${year}`).getDay()];
};

console.log(dayOfTheWeek(3, 11, 2020));
```

The second solution is [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) built-in method.

```js
var dayOfTheWeek = (day, month, year) => {
  return new Date(year, month - 1, day).toLocaleString("en-US", {
    weekday: "long",
  });
};

console.log(dayOfTheWeek(3, 11, 2020));
```

The third solution is based on **[Zeller's congruence](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Zeller%27s_congruence)**.

```js
function zeller(day, month, year) {
  const weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  if (month < 3) {
    month += 12;
    year--;
  }
  var h = (day + parseInt(((month + 1) * 26) / 10) +
    year + parseInt(year / 4) + 6 * parseInt(year / 100) +
    parseInt(year / 400) - 1) % 7;
  return weekday[h];
}
console.log(zeller(3, 11, 2020));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const language = 'en-us';
const options = {  weekday: 'long' };
const today = new Date().toLocaleString(language, options)
cosnsole.log(today)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let today= new Date()

//Function To Convert Day Integer to String

function daysToSrting() {
  const daysOfWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday','Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
  return daysOfWeek[today.getDay()]
}

console.log(daysToSrting())
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26280394)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let weekday = ['Sunday',
               'Monday',
               'Tuesday',
               'Wednesday',
               'Thursday',
               'Friday',
               'Saturday'][new Date().getDay()];

console.log(weekday)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the library `moment`.

```
const moment = require('moment')
console.log(moment(person.dateOfBirth,'DD.MM.YYYY').format("dddd {d}"))
```

Output:

```
Monday {1}
```

Answer (score 1):

If needed, the full name of a day ("Monday" for example) can be obtained by using `Intl.DateTimeFormat` with an options parameter.

```
var Xmas95 = new Date('December 25, 1995 23:15:30');

var options = { weekday: 'long'};
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(Xmas95));
// Monday
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('de-DE', options).format(Xmas95));
// Montag
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my two cents... moment (which maybe is not the best library option) has a method:

```
moment.weekdays(1) // Monday
moment.weekdaysShort(1) //Mon
```

By the way it is locale dependent so it gives you the name in the language set, that is why I chose this option.

Answer (score 1):

If there are any **Angular** users, there is a pipe to achieve this.

```
{{yourDate | date:'EEEE'}}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function whatday(num) { 
  switch(num) {
    case 1:
      return "Sunday";
    case 2:
      return "Monday";
    case 3:
      return "Tuesday";
    case 4:
      return "Wednesday";
    case 5:
      return "Thursday";
    case 6:
      return "Friday";
    case 7:
      return "Saturday";
    default:
      return 'Wrong, please enter a number between 1 and 7';
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: days of the week in JS are 0-6. NOT 1-7. This is off by 1