# Enjoy the rest of your (day) message

Tags: jquery, html

I've been toying around with getDay() and HTML5 Data Attributes to try and display a message similar to Basecamp's footer.

"Enjoy the rest of your Sunday!"
https://basecamp.com/

I've managed to achieve returning the day of the week using jquery, but not sure how to apply that to the data attribute.

Would love some assistance. Thanks.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677757/how-to-get-the-day-of-the-week-from-the-day-number-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have something like this in html code

```
<p>Enjoy the rest of your <span data-day="wday"></span>!</p>
```

Define a javascript function like so :

```
function dayOfWeekAsString(idx) {
      return ["Sunday", "Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][idx];
    }
```

Then you can just do

```
var d=new Date();
var day_idx = d.getDay();
var week_day = dayOfWeekAsString(day_idx);
$("p").find("[data-day='wday']").html(week_day);
```

EDIT: Updated code with Jsfiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mdjaman/ts5ce8L5/1/)

```js
function dayOfWeekAsString(idx) {
  return ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"][idx];
}


var d = new Date();
var day_idx = d.getDay();
var week_day = dayOfWeekAsString(day_idx);
$("p").find("[data-day='wday']").html(week_day);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Enjoy the rest of your <span data-day="wday"></span>!</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did something similar myself, which works, however, it doesn't use the HTML data attribute which is something I wanted to try.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Marcel!