# Javascript display the "day" instead of the "number"

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript that will determine the day of the week:

```
<script>
 function myFunction() {
   var d = new Date();
   var n = d.getDay()
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
 }
</script>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Running this code, it'll display `4`. Is there anyway I can convert this to an actual string/word like `thursday`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677757/how-to-get-the-day-of-the-week-from-the-day-number-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use an array

```
 var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
 var day = days[ now.getDay() ];
```

Comment: moment.js is a good library for managing dates in js

Comment: @DaleCorns   .. yes is useful too this the link https://momentjs.com

Comment: No, no ,no ,no. Just use the standard javascript Date class. No need for arrays or an extra library. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50293232/760777

Answer (score 1):

You can use that number as an index to an array of actual day names:

```
var days = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'];
var date = new Date();
var day = days[date.getDay()];
```