# Get the days of the week starting from today

Tags: javascript, date

I am implementing a chart to display the daily data. At the moment I can only write the static data like.

```
data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
```

How can I write a function to get this starting from current day and time.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Use [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com) with its wide range of functions (e.g. [start-of](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/))

Comment: [`Date.prototype.getDay()` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay): _"The `.getDay()` method returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where 0 represents Sunday."_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the day of the week from the day number in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677757/how-to-get-the-day-of-the-week-from-the-day-number-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function here will populate an array over and over again with days `Mon..Sun` `n` times starting from the current day of the week:

```
function populateDateArray(n = 7) {
    var daysInAWeek = [ 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat' ];
    var returnValue = new Array(n);
    var currentDay = (new Date().getDay()); //0 = sunday
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        returnValue[i] = daysInAWeek[(currentDay++) % 7];
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

What we do is get the current day of the week by doing `new Date().getDay()` - this will return the date in numeric form (0 = sunday, 1 = monday.... 6 = saturday).

After this, we then iterate `n` times, grabbing `daysInAWeek` from the `current day of the week + 1`. This would usually cause overflow, so we will take the `modulo 7` of this result which will bound the value between `0..6`.

As a result, when we get to **saturday** it will then loop back to the start of `daysInAWeek` and go to **sunday** (and then over and over again).

Usage: `var days = populateDateArray(28); //get 28 days from today`

Comment: Thanks for the working example.. Also if i have to make it work on hourly basis, do I have to do the similar stuff?

Comment: If you want to do it on an hourly basis (hours 1-24) you can do the same just by adding to the `daysInAWeek` array and then changing `% 7` to `% 24` (or, for a more generic case, `% daysInAWeek.length`)