# Get the date from day number of week Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have a model in my database that contains an array called "AvailableDays" [0...6]. 0 = Sunday & 6 = Saturday. I am looking to convert this day number of the week to the date of day in the current week.

For example, this is the logic broken down

1. Retrieve the list of available days (`const availableDays = [0,2,4,6]`)
2. Get the current DATE (`const today = new Date('2021-08-20');`)
3. Covert day numbers to dates (`output =['15-08-2021', '17-08-2021', '19-08-2021', '21-08-2021']`)

Comment: I would actually suggest _changing_ your database design here.  Instead of storing the number day of the week, store actual proper dates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the day of the week from the day number in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677757/how-to-get-the-day-of-the-week-from-the-day-number-in-javascript)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I assume he has some kind of scheduling app where the available  days repeat evey week and he wants to find the dates in the current week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is get the day-of-the-week from the given `Date` instance and work out the offset from your *available day*.

Then subtract that offset in days from the given date to produce your result.

```js
const transformDate = (date, day) => {
  const offset = date.getDay() - day
  
  const d = new Date(date)
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - offset)
  return d
}

const availableDays = [0,2,4,6]
const today = new Date("2021-08-20")

console.log(availableDays.map(day => transformDate(today, day)))
```

Comment: Stack Snippets seem broken (at least for me) right now so apologies if the example isn't runnable

Comment: Yes but the problem is resolved now, you missed a `)` in `console.log` methods :)

Comment: @Phil Thanks a lot, I was able to solve this myself but your answer is more complete than mine. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @TomDickson it's basically the same thing. I'm very glad you were able to figure it out yourself

Answer (score 1):

You can generate all the days in weeks and then get the dates using `availableDays`.

```js
const getWeekDays = (current) => {
    current.setDate((current.getDate() - current.getDay() - 1));
    return Array.from({ length: 7 }, (_, i) => {
      current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1)
      return new Date(current).toLocaleDateString('en-CA');
    });
  },
  today = new Date('2021-08-20'),
  weekDays = getWeekDays(today),
  availableDays = [0, 2, 4, 6],
  availableDates = availableDays.map(day => weekDays[day]);
console.log(availableDates);
```

Comment: On the input side, '2021-08-20' is parsed as UTC. Then in *getWeekDays*, *toISOString* is used to get the date parts. So users with a negative offset see dates one day later than expected (16, 18, 20, 22 Aug) whereas users with a positive offset see expected dates (15, 17, 19, 21). Also, getting an array of all week days to then filter out the unwanted ones is somewhat inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to solve this myself. I am now able to wrap this into a availableDates.map() and return an array of dates using the below logic.

```js
var availableDay = 0
var d = new Date(),
    day = d.getDay(), // 0 ... 6
    calcAvailableDay = day-availableDay,
    diff = d.getDate() - calcAvailableDay,
    output = new Date(d.setDate(diff));
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript [getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) method returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where 0 represents Sunday.

So what you have to do is connect this index with your `availableDays` values.

**Logic**

- Get current date, month, year and the index of todays date.
- Loop through the `availableDays` array, and create new dates with the difference between the current day calculated with `getDay` value and the day value specified in your array.
- Make use of some logic to reperesent those date object in specified format. I took support from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531093/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-in-javascript) post to format your date string.

```js
const availableDays = [0,2,4,6];
const today = new Date();
const currentDay = today.getDay();
const currentDate = today.getDate();
const currentMonth = today.getMonth();
const currentYear = today.getFullYear();
formatDateToString = (date) => String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0') + '-' + String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0') + '-' + date.getFullYear();
const output = availableDays.map((day) => formatDateToString(new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate - (currentDay - day))));
console.log(output);
```