# Javascript - getting a specific day of the week

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner at javascript, and I'm looking just for a way to generate a specific day of the week, without any conditions, which I want to practice myself. I'm going through some confusion while reading the documentation. Basically, what I want to tell the javascript is to display a  tag at a certain day of the week, at a certain time of the day.

For instance, display  on Monday between 19:00-21:00.

I have this and I don't really know how to change whatever is in the element. I feel like I'm not going anywhere with this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
element = document.getElementById('broadcast-live')
var datestart = new Date("December 28, 2012 17:00:00")
var date_end = new Date("December 28, 2012 22:00:00")

function DisplayLiveBroadcast()
{
    if (new Date => datestart)
    {
        document.write("<div id=\"broadcast-live\">Live on air (Started Friday, 21:00)<div/>")
    }
    else if (new Date => date_end)
    {
        document.write("<div id=\"broadcast-live\"> <div/>")
    }
    else
    {
            document.write("<div id=\"broadcast-live\"> <div/>")
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have any code you've tried already that we could see?

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? To find out which weekday it is for a given day?

Comment: I've only tried a function and an if statement, but this is as far as I got, I'm tiny confused with the Date() function.

Comment: @zzwyb89 hint. `Date()` isn't terribly useful. Use it as a constructor: `new Date()`

Comment: There are 2 questions there. First, how to find out if you're in a specific range. Second, how to get the data from a Google Docs spreadsheet. For the first question, remember that Javascript is on the client. Which means that Monday 19:00-21:00 is not the same for me and the people in different timezones. For the second question, you'd better ask another question.

Comment: I'm attempting to display the <div> tag with text inside it only on the specified date and time in the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the day from a particular date using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495644/how-to-get-the-day-from-a-particular-date-using-javascript)

Comment: I've added the code I've written to the first post, I'm not sure if it would work. It is not exactly what I wanted, but it will do for now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out, which uses a `getDay()` method that returns an integer value referring to the current day: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Comment: http://w3fools.com/ why not point to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) isntead

Comment: It's saddening to see high rep people linking to w3schools.

Comment: I had a look at this, thank you, but I believe it's returning the current day we have? The thing I want to achieve, is for JS to check what day it is, and using an if statement (I guess?) display the div tag, else leave it as it is e.g <div class="broadcast-live></div>

Comment: I've added the code I've written to the first post, I'm not sure if it would work. It is not exactly what I wanted, but it will do for now.