# Display day of the week with Javascript date

Tags: javascript

I am using the code below to display a date 7 days in the future. However this javascript code formats the date by mm/dd/yyyy.

I would like to modify the javascript code below to have it display the day of the week instead such as **Friday, Nov 1**

I do not need it to display the year.

Any help would be much appreciated as I am stumped.

```
<script>
var myDate=new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+7);
var n=myDate.toLocaleDateString();
document.write(n);
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this , adding 1 week from current day  output you get  is :**Friday,November 1**

```
<script >
<!--

var m_names = ["January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
"October", "November", "December"];

var d_names = ["Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+7);
var curr_date = myDate.getDate();
var curr_month = myDate.getMonth();
var curr_day  = myDate.getDay();
document.write(d_names[curr_day] + "," + m_names[curr_month] + " " +curr_date);

//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you :) That is exactly what I was hoping to achieve.

Comment: Sasi, I was wondering if you could help me modify this code to adjust for weekends. I have posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616180/make-javascript-future-date-adjust-for-weekends

Answer (score 4):

[Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) has a `getDay()` method which returns a day number, starting with Sunday on 0 and continuing with Monday=1, Tuesday=2 and so on.

You can use that to return just the week day. See [How to get the day from a particular date using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495644/how-to-get-the-day-from-a-particular-date-using-javascript) and similar questions.

```
document.write(["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][myDate.getDay()]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. However the code you provided now makes the javascript only show the day of the week. I also want it to display the month followed by the actual date number.