# make Javascript future date adjust for weekends

Tags: javascript

I am using the following javascript code to display 7 days into the future based off the current date.

```
<script >
<!--

var m_names = ["January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
"October", "November", "December"];

var d_names = ["Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+7);
var curr_date = myDate.getDate();
var curr_month = myDate.getMonth();
var curr_day  = myDate.getDay();
document.write(d_names[curr_day] + "," + m_names[curr_month] + " " +curr_date);

//-->
</script>
```

I am using this javascript code to let my customers know when they will get their packages by.

The script automatically adds 7 days to the current date. I would like it to adjust the future date (+7) if the current date falls on a Saturday or Sunday.

**If the current date is a Saturday I would like it to add (+9 days). If the current date is a Sunday I would like it to add (+8 days)**

All current days that fall between Monday-Friday I would like it to add (+7 days).

Any thoughts on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Make the `7` as `9` for all the dates, if a weekend comes in the middle. i.e., if the current day is Tuesday, and the number of days is more than `6`, then add `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following CompuChip's answer (sorry, C, it got too long for a comment!):

```
if (myDate.getDay() == 5) // Saturday
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+9);
else
if (myDate.getDay() == 6) // Sunday
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+8);
else
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+7);
```

You could also use a `switch` statement here (and if you don't know how to: this is a *perfect* moment to look it up and experiment with it!).

A third interesting way is to use an array. Now you know Monday=0, Tuesday=1, etc., you can build a list of values-to-add for every weekday:

```
var nextWeek = [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 8];
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+nextWeek[myDate.getDay()]);
```

However, there is a strict relation between day-of-week number and the adjust value:

```
myDate.setDate( myDate.getDate()+ ((myDate.getDay() < 5) ? 7 : 14-myDate.getDay()) );
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. The first method worked best :) You Rock!

Comment: Actually a slight improvement may be assigning myDate.getDay to a variable, so you can prevent retrieving (probably calculating?) it 5 times.

Comment: @CompuChip: yes, that's why I suggested the `switch`. It seems to OP went for the first -- technically *worst* -- alternative. I'd most likely use a switch, as it's a compromise between an endless list of if..elses and the rigidness of an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .getDay() method to find out the weekday.
E.g

```
if (myDate.getDay() == 5) // Saturday
```

Note the days start at 0 for Monday, 1 for Tuesday, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however unfortunately I am not good at all when it comes to javascript. I have No clue how to insert this.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple really:

```
var days = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

function getFutureDate(date) {
    switch (date.getDay()) {
    case 0:  return new Date(date.getTime() + 8 * days);
    case 6:  return new Date(date.getTime() + 9 * days);
    default: return new Date(date.getTime() + 7 * days);
    }
}
```

Now you can use `getFutureDate` as follows:

```
var futureDate = getFutureDate(new Date);
```

However we can write an even more general solution:

```
var milliseconds = 1
  , seconds      = 1000 * milliseconds
  , minutes      = 60 * seconds
  , hours        = 60 * minutes
  , days         = 24 * hours
  , weeks        = 7 * days;

function addDate(date, time) {
    return new Date(date.getTime() + time);
}
```

Now we can rewrite our `getFutureDate` function as follows:

```
function getFutureDate(date) {
    switch (date.getDay()) {
    case 0:  return addDate(date, 1 * weeks + 1 * days);
    case 6:  return addDate(date, 1 * weeks + 2 * days);
    default: return addDate(date, 1 * weeks + 0 * days);
    }
}
```

Of course in this case it would be better to simply use the old `getFutureDate` function. However I just wanted to show you how you could add (or subtract) an arbitrary amount of time from your dates.