# Day of the week display using ''switch" statement.(Issue)

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

I'm experiencing a problem with a switch statement that displays a day of the week. I want to take an input from the user(a number) and to display a day of the week. Here is my source code, please point out what's wrong with my function.

```js
let clickButton = document.getElementById("button");
clickButton.addEventListener("click", function weekDay() {

  let day = Number(document.getElementById("numberDay").value);

  switch (day) {

    case 0:
      alert("It's Sunday!")
      break;
    case 1:
      alert("It's Monday");
      break;
    case 2:
      alert("It's Tuesday");
      break;
    case 3:
      alert("It's Wednesday");
      break;
    case 4:
      alert("It's Thursday");
      break;
    case 5:
      alert("It's Friday");
      break;
    case 6:
      alert("It's Saturday");
      break;

  }

})
```

```html
Enter a number: <input type="text" id="numberDay">
<button id="button">OK</button>
```

Comment: Your code is fine, but it's 0 based. Take the input - 1 to get the correct day. In addition, you should avoid a switch in this case, and just use an array `['Sunday', 'Monday',...]`, and get the day using `arr[input - 1]`.

Comment: You might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583312/display-day-of-the-week-with-javascript-date).

Comment: @Xonshiz OP is simply taking a number as input and displaying a string based on that using `switch`. This has little to do with `getDay` returning  zero based number

Comment: _"I'm experiencing a problem..."_ - What is the problem that you are experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. But you might want to add a default case if the user inputs something else besides 0-6 numbers. 
Maybe add another case for number 7 to be used for Sunday as well.

```js
switch (day) {

    case 0:
    case 7:
      alert("It's Sunday!")
      break;
    case 1:
      alert("It's Monday");
      break;
    case 2:
      alert("It's Tuesday");
      break;
    case 3:
      alert("It's Wednesday");
      break;
    case 4:
      alert("It's Thursday");
      break;
    case 5:
      alert("It's Friday");
      break;
    case 6:
      alert("It's Saturday");
      break;
    default: 
      alert("Wrong input!");
      break;

  }
```

Might as well change the input type from `text` to `number`

```html
<input type="number" id="numberDay">
```

Or is there any other issue you are experiencing?

Comment: Well, when I click the button, it alerts nothing. I think it supposed to work, but nothing happens.

Comment: The weird thing is, that when I run it here - it works :D. Not in my browser though.

Comment: Double check your Classes / Ids, and throw some `console.log()`s in to make sure you're entering the function when you would expect