# Get name of day from date (dd-mm-yyyy)

Tags: javascript, date

What is the best solution to return name of day from this date format dd-mm-yyyy?

If date is 10-03-2014, script return Monday.

What about moment.js?

Comment: Get the day number https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay. Then use it as an index to get the day as text form an array of days.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495644/how-to-get-the-day-from-a-particular-date-using-javascript here use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
var d = new Date();
var dayNames=['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun']

alert(dayNames[d.getDay()-1]);
```

if you get undefine then you need to do some improvement first is date formate
 you have to format date before passing the date in Date() function //Supported Formate for Date constructor

```
    //var d = new Date(2011, 01, 07); // yyyy, mm-1, dd
    //var d = new Date(2011, 01, 07, 11, 05, 00); // yyyy, mm-1, dd, hh, mm, ss
    //var d = new Date("02/07/2011 11:05:00"); // "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    //var d = new Date(1297076700000); // milliseconds
    //var d = new Date(Feb 07 2011)//mm/dd/yyy
    //var d = new Date(16 Mar 2014)//dd/mm/yyy  <------USE THIS 
    //var d = new Date("Mon Feb 07 2011 11:05:00 GMT"); // ""Day Mon dd yyyy hh:mm:ss GMT/UTC
    //var d = new Date("02/07/2011"); // "mm/dd/yyyy" IE8,IE9
```

Now change the code to :

```
var d = new Date("16 Mar 2014");
var n = d.getDay();
var days = new Array("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wen","Thi","Fri","Sat");
alert(days[n]);
```

Comment: This will not work. If day is Sunday then day will be 0 and `dayNames[d.getDay()-1` will be undefined

Comment: of course you have to do some modification in that to adopt that for your requirement . For me its work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date(2014,02,10);
var day = date.getDay();
```

day will be shown as a number.

Then you can construct an array in your language to retrieve the day name

```
var daysName = ['Sunday','Monday'...];

alert(daysName[day]);
```

Comment: This will not work. If day is Sunday then day will be 0 and `daysName[day-1]` will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

This will give you perfect output.

```
function Day_name(custom_date) 
{
     var myDate=custom_date;
     myDate=myDate.split("-");
     var newDate=myDate[2]+"-"+myDate[1]+"-"+myDate[0];
     var my_ddate=new Date(newDate).getTime();
     var currentDate = new Date(newDate);
     var day_name = currentDate.getDay();
     var days = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
     return days[day_name];
}
```

call like this `Day_name("02-04-2015");`

output you will get like `Thursday`